# Groupoid objects in the category of algebras

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Can anyone give me some references where I could read about groupoid objects in the category of algebras?

References about groupoid objects in other categories would also be welcome.

Comment: This is a very vague question...

Comment: Do you really want groupoid objects, not cogroupoid objects? The latter are Hopf algebroids, which are very useful, but the former seem strange. Are there any group objects at all, for instance?

Comment: Well I don't know much about it. It is a theme for a seminar, it was not me who chose it. But, cogroupoid objects could also be useful.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I found out groupoids in the category of algebras are the "same" as extensions of algebras by bimodules. Later on I'll post the discussion.